# i want to print a matrix into an txt file using a display function

Tags: c++, file, outputstream

i want to output a matrix into a txt file using a display function ( i tried to do it without the displayDor function and still didn't work)
the error is in the last line inside the function enregistrer line 48

and its saying :
[Error] no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream}' and 'void')

the code is the following  :

```
01 -#include <iostream>
02 -#include<ctime>
03 -#include<cstdlib>
04 -#include<fstream>
05 -using namespace std;
06 -struct Case{
07 -    bool N,W,S,E;
08 -    };
09 -    
10 -struct laby{
11 -    int p;
12 -    int q;
13 -    Case **tab;
14 -    };
15 -    
16 -laby *cree_laby(int p,int q){
17 -    laby *labyr=new laby;
18 -    labyr->p=p;
19 -    labyr->q=q;
20 -    labyr->tab=new Case*[p];
21 -    for(int i=0;i<p;i++){
22 -        labyr->tab[i]=new Case[q];
23 -        for(int j=0;j<q;j++){
24 -            labyr->tab[i][j].N=false;
25 -            labyr->tab[i][j].W=false;
26 -            labyr->tab[i][j].S=false;
27 -            labyr->tab[i][j].E=false;
28 -            }
29 -        }
30 -    return labyr;
31 -    }
32 -    
33 -void displayLaby(const laby &labyr){
34 -    for(int i=0;i<labyr.p;i++){
35 -        for(int j=0;j<labyr.q;j++){
36 -            cout<<'['<<labyr.tab[i][j].N<<','<<labyr.tab[i][j].E<<','<<labyr.tab[i][j].S<<','<<labyr.tab[i][j].W<<']';
37 -            }
38 -            cout<<"\n";
39 -        }
40 -    }
41 -    
42 -void enregistrer(laby & labyr,char *filename){
43 -    ofstream f;
44 -    f.open(filename);
45 -    f<<labyr.p;
46 -    f<<labyr.q;
47 -    f<<endl;
48 -    f<<displayLaby(labyr);
49 -}
50 -
51 -int main(){
52 -    laby *labyr;
53 -    labyr=cree_laby(5,5);
54 -    enregistrer(*labyr,"laby.txt");
55 -    return 0;
56 -    }
```

i tried to use a function display and i used loops also to output the maze into a txt file but they are both not working,

i would appreciate the help,
Thank you,

Comment: your displayLaby function always outputs to cout, it never outputs to f

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with actual code. `f<<displayLaby(labyr)` doesn't compile and reports an explicit message: _"error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ofstream' {aka 'std::basic_ofstream<char>'} and 'void')"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `displayLaby` writes to `std::cout`, if you want it to write somewhere else (like a file) then you have to *pass the stream as a parameter* to the function. Like this

```
void displayLaby(const laby &labyr, ostream& os){
    for(int i=0;i<labyr.p;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<labyr.q;j++){
            os<<'['<<labyr.tab[i][j].N<<','<<labyr.tab[i][j].E<<','<<labyr.tab[i][j].S<<','<<labyr.tab[i][j].W<<']';
        }
        os<<"\n";
    }
}

void enregistrer(laby & labyr,char *filename){
    ofstream f;
    f.open(filename);
    f<<labyr.p;
    f<<labyr.q;
    f<<endl;
    displayLaby(labyr, f);
}
```

Here `os` is the new parameter, and writes go to that stream instead of `cout`. The type of the new parameter is `ostream&` which means it will work for any kind of output stream. Of course if you want to write to `cout` anyway then you just call the new function like this `displayLaby(labyr, cout);`.

Comment: still the same error its saying 
[Error] no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' and 'void')

Comment: @LilOLD Look again at the code I wrote, and compare it to the code you have, The way you call `displayLaby` has changed.